# Fill a cell when empty, and past a date in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I need a cell in column "B" to fill red, if it is empty and the date is past the date on column "M"

I have tried googling it, and there are no answers to help.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired formatting in Excel, you can use conditional formatting. Here's a step-by-step guide to setting it up:

Select the range of cells in column B where you want the formatting to be applied. For example, if your data starts from B2 and goes down to B100, select B2:B100.

Go to the "Home" tab on the Excel ribbon.

Click on "Conditional Formatting" in the "Styles" group.

Choose "New Rule" from the dropdown menu.

In the "New Formatting Rule" dialog box, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format."

In the "Format values where this formula is true" box, enter the following formula:

less
=AND(B2="", M2<TODAY())

This formula checks if cell B2 is empty and if the date in cell M2 is less than today's date.

Click on the "Format" button to choose the formatting you want to apply. In this case, select the "Fill" tab, and choose the red color for the cells.

Click "OK" to close the "Format Cells" dialog box.

Click "OK" again in the "New Formatting Rule" dialog box.

The cells in column B that are empty and have a date past the date in column M will now be filled with the red color.